# MongoDB too slow when using both $gte and $lte in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using MongoDB for first time in my project and now I am facing a big challenge. This project is used to store huge amount of log data and now we already collected 8 million records.I am using Laravel MongoDB library created by jenssegers.

Here are the details of challenges I am facing with MongoDB.

I need to display the logs in a table with pagination for a specific network type collected within a certain range of time. To have pagination I need to know the total count of filtered records. But unfortunately **the selective count is extremely slow in MongoDB**.

Here is the code I used for selective count

```
$start_time = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($fromDate)* 1000);
$end_time = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime($tillDate)* 1000);

$totalData = Location::raw(function($collection) use($network_id, $start_time, $end_time) {
                        return $collection->count(["network_id" => $network_id],['created_at' => array('$gt' => $start_time, '$lt' => $end_time)]);
                });
```

Now the second and most important challenge I am facing is **MongoDB too slow when using both $gte and $lte**. If i use only one ie $lte or $gte I get results instantly. But if i used both, Then it is extremely slow.

Here is code I used to get logs between certain date range

```
    $locations = Location::query();

    if (! empty($network_id)) {
        $locations = $locations->where('network_id', $network_id);
    }

    if ($hour != null) {
        $locations =  $locations->where('created_at','>=',$start_time)
                                ->where('created_at','<=',$end_time);
    } 

    $locations =  $locations->offset($start)
                            ->limit(1000)
                            ->orderBy('_id','DESC')
                            ->get();
```

Here is my live server details,
I am hosted it on AWS on 1 core Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2676 v3 @ 2.40GHz with 1gb ram and 4gb swap memory.

If anybody has previous experience with these situation please help me.

Comment: And what indexes if any are present on the collection? Have you tried actually running the expected query through the mongo shell and using the `explain()` option to see the results? If not then that is a good place to start, and include the details with your question.

Comment: @NeilLunn . I already run the raw query in shell and still it is too slow. I indexed both _id and network_id. db.locations.getIndexes()
[
 {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "_id_",
  "ns" : "m.locations"
 },
 {
  "v" : 2,
  "key" : {
   "network_id" : 1
  },
  "name" : "network_id_1",
  "ns" : "m.locations"
 }
]
I also tried this query by indexing created_at but still it doen't give me any improvements so i removed it.

Comment: Yeah well there's no index on the field as of running that command now is there. You need to add an index for things to work at their optimal performance. The other clear problem is the "skip" and "limit" which are certainly not optimal and should be avoided in favor of "ranged paging" wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have indexes if its fast when using one parameter. But using multiple columns will most likely result in a full table scan. (I say may because I'm not that intimate with Mongo but this is generally the case with other DBs).

You should look at [compound indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/). *"where a single index structure holds references to multiple fields"* You could add an index which uses both your columns.

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "network_id": 1, "created_at": -1} )
```

This is a general database design problem not specific to Mongo. And its important to note adding indexes will result in slower write speeds. You should consider removing all other indexes and only have one or two that your analytics queries use. Particularly if this is a log stash.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. I create compound index by copying your code and now my second problem is solved. If you can please also give me suggestion to solve my first problem ie the selective count is extremely slow in MongoDB.

Comment: I solved the first problem too. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it was solved. Could you post what the solution was.

Comment: The first problem is already solved when i compound indexed the fields. But in my code i doen't check whether i have values for network_id and start and end time. I enclose them in a if condition to check whether i have values for network_id and  start and end times.